# Is this でも or で＋も?

Tags: grammar, particles

This is similar to a [previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12564/particle-interpretation-of-%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82) of mine. Also from Kanji in Context, we have the example sentence (with no other context)

> 東京｛とうきょう｝**でも**雪｛ゆき｝は降｛ふ｝りますが、たいていは大｛たい｝して積｛つ｝もりません。

Is it possible to determine whether the でも here is でも (even in Tokyo, it snows) or で(location of action) + も (it also snows in Tokyo)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Formal vs. Informal***

I am going to say that:

1) In ***informal*** speech, both interpretations are almost equally natural.

2) In ***formal*** speech, however, it would be considerably more appropriate to interpret the 「でも」 as being 「で + も」(location + "also").

Here is my reasoning.

If one said 「東京**でも**雪は降る」 in formal speech to mean "It snows ***even*** in Tokyo.", then one would have to wonder where the location marker is because 「でも」 is all taken to express "even".

In formal speech, one would instead need to use 「東京で**さえも**」 or 「東京で**でも**」 to express both "**even**" and "**in**".  Admittedly, though, the latter would rarely be heard in real life as it is a mouthful.

「Place Name + で + でも」 is very often contracted to 「Place Name + でも」 in informal speech, which is the main reason that, in informal speech, 「東京でも雪は降る」 can naturally be interpreted to mean both:

"It snows in Tokyo, too." and "It snows even in Tokyo."

Comment: Thanks very much, 「さえ」 is a new word for me. It seems that 「さえ」 by itself conveys the idea of "even", would it be okay to say 「東京でさえ」instead of 「東京でさえも」and is there any difference between the two?

Comment: There is no difference between 「東京でさえ」and「東京でさえも」.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because it says in the end, that the snow is rarely piling up very high.
The whole translation would be like this.
Even in Tokyo it snows, but mostly it doesn't pile up too much.

The word たいてい Indicates that it is a general matter.

Comment: Does "yes" mean でも or で＋も?